# Unable to set a custom error page for HTTP 413

Tags: .net, iis, iis-10

An IIS Web site uses the request filtering setting [maxAllowedContentLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits/#attributes) to reject upload of too big files (approximately more than 10 megabytes). This value is in bytes, its configured global value on the Web site server is 200kB, so we raise it to `10000000` on the path needing to accept uploads. (I know that is not exactly 10MB, but that is fine for us.)

As this is a .Net Framework Web site, we also configure the .Net [`maxRequestLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength). This value is in kilobytes, its default value is 4MB, so we raise it to `10000`.

```xml
<location path="the-adequate-path">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I am trying to setup a custom error page to display when a request is rejected due to this setting. The HTTP error code for this case is `413`. But instead of replacing the default error response properly, the following configuration of IIS `httpErrors` yields a blank page with a 413 status:

```xml
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="413" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Errors/Page/404" />
  <error statusCode="413" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Errors/Page/413" />
</httpErrors>
```

The 404 case works perfectly fine, but not the 413 case. In both cases, the executed URL is a .Net Framework MVC action. In debug, we can see 404 going through the MVC action, but not the 413.

How can we define an in-place custom error page for this content request too big error?
(I do not want a redirect to somewhere else.)

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is caused by the response mode `ExecuteURL`. In this mode, the server execute another URL to get the HTML of the error response.

It seems it does so while keeping the context of the failed request, including its content-length, causing the "request too big error" to be triggered for the executed error response URL too. That would cause that behavior of just yielding an empty error page with adequate status code.

Switching the response mode to `File` and changing the error path for a static file can solve the issue, but that means using a static file instead of the MVC error action.

Instead, it is possible to change the limits for the MVC error action, to somewhat disable them (raise their limit enough for reasonable attempts of uploads). It does work for `maxAllowedContentLength`. For `maxRequestLength`, trying that causes a server error: instead, it has to be "disabled" (set to its max value) globally.

So, I was able to get it work with following configuration:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <remove statusCode="413" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Errors/Page/404" />
    <error statusCode="413" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Errors/Page/413" />
  </httpErrors>
  ...
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
  ...
  <!-- Disable maxRequestLength by raising it to its maximal value: the IIS maxAllowedContentLength
       is used instead. -->
  <httpRuntime ... maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  ...
</system.web>

<location path="Errors">
  <!-- Raise the size limit to 1GB for the errors controller, otherwise the error page itself
       is blocked in case of "too big file" error.
       (So, uploads even bigger than 1GB will not have an adequate error message, so long for them.) -->
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>

<location path="the-adequate-path">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```